# in range input, when min and max are equal, the slide should just be a dot?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="1" value="50">
```

But it is not a dot:

[image]

How to make it a dot?

Comment: I don't understand, you mean the slider with shape equal to a dot?

Comment: Why you want to use slider in a way where it is not usable for a user at all ? How can it consider a valid use case ? Providing an element to the user and that is not usable and user can't interact with that, it breaks the usability and web accessibility principle. If it is a dynamic form, where you can control the values, just hide the element.

Comment: I guess you will need to use javascript to set the width of the input.

Comment: I would use the checkbox in this case.

Comment: A dot? Instead of the blue circle? When? Your question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps you ..

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  if(parseInt(slider.getAttribute('min')) == parseInt(slider.getAttribute('max'))){
    slider.style.width=0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="1" value="50">
```

Answer (score 1):

give a id to your `input`

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="1" id="rangeInput" />
```

Then add following javascript code for running in the page:

```
const rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeInput");
if (rangeInput.min === rangeInput.max) {
   rangeInput.style.width = "0px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just need to set its width to zero

```css
input{
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="1" value="50">
```

Comment: I think this will not work if the max value is greater than min value